# Running Cygwin VIM in a cmd shell occasionally fails

Tags: vim, cygwin, windows-7-x64

I am using the current Cygwin and VIM editor on Windows 7. Once or twice a day when I start VIM in a cmd shell, the system seems to pause, then the shell window disappears. It will leave a filename.txt.swp file in the current directory. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does this (Vim fails) happened in Cygwin's mintty? I didn't encounter this problem before.

"system seems to pause" do you mean the Windows system pause? or just Vim pause?

How do you open the cmd window? (Not sure if it matters)

I found I can open Vim in a cmd in two ways:

1. `cygstart tcsh` and then open `vim` in it
2. Add `C:\cygwin64\bin` into Windows' `PATH` variable, open a cmd window and open `vim`

but both method works fine (although the font in cmd is not fine at all)

Comment: I am running in method 2 as you describe. Usually, it works well. Occasionally, after a pause, the cmd shell dissapears and a .swp file is left. No error messages. No warnings.